# ID Select ,select statement

Tags: database, vb.net

I have a table with following columns:

- Emp_id varchar(50)
- Emp_Name varchar(50)
- Emp_surname varchar(50)
- Emp_manager varchar(50)

Sample data:

```
ID           Name           Surname            Manager
--------------------------------------------------------
emp001       Jannnie        van Rensburg       emp002
emp002       Sannie         Retief             None
```

So sannie is jannie manager. I need a query that display following in a report

```
ID           Name           Surname              Manager
---------------------------------------------------------------
emp001       Jannie         van Rensburg         Sannie Retief
```

Any help would be appreciated thanks.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should try something like this:

```
select t1.emp_id ,t1.name || ' , ' || t1.surname , t2.name|| ' , ' t2.surname
from yourtable t1 
inner join yourtable t2 
  on t2.Emp_id=t1.Emp_manager
```